# MySQL hierarchical tree-like sorting query without using assignment operator

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query, treesort

I have hierarchical tree structured sorting query based on [explainextended](https://explainextended.com/2009/07/20/hierarchical-data-in-mysql-parents-and-children-in-one-query/)

Now I need to change query with "WITH RECURSIVE" due to MySQL 8+ future removal of assignment operator (:=).

Here is sample of my question:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`TestTable` (
`id` INT NOT NULL,
`parentid` INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

INSERT INTO `test`.`TestTable` (`id`, `parentid`) VALUES ('1', '0');
INSERT INTO `test`.`TestTable` (`id`, `parentid`) VALUES ('2', '1');
INSERT INTO `test`.`TestTable` (`id`, `parentid`) VALUES ('3', '1');
INSERT INTO `test`.`TestTable` (`id`, `parentid`) VALUES ('4', '2');
INSERT INTO `test`.`TestTable` (`id`, `parentid`) VALUES ('5', '3');
INSERT INTO `test`.`TestTable` (`id`, `parentid`) VALUES ('6', '2');
INSERT INTO `test`.`TestTable` (`id`, `parentid`) VALUES ('7', '2');
INSERT INTO `test`.`TestTable` (`id`, `parentid`) VALUES ('8', '3');
INSERT INTO `test`.`TestTable` (`id`, `parentid`) VALUES ('9', '3');

WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS (
    SELECT id, parentid, 1 AS level
    FROM test.TestTable
    WHERE id=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.id, p.parentid, level + 1
    FROM CTE
    INNER JOIN test.TestTable p ON p.parentid=CTE.id
)
SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

The output shows as below

```
   id    parentid   level
    1           0       1
    2           1       2
    3           1       2
    4           2       3
    5           3       3
    6           2       3
    7           2       3
    8           3       3
    9           3       3
```

However, what I am looking for is to display tree like results looks like

```
   id    parentid   level
    1           0       1
    2           1       2
    4           2       3
    6           2       3
    7           2       3
    3           1       2
    5           3       3
    8           3       3
    9           3       3
```

Is there a way to make this results using "WITH RECURSIVE"?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS (
    SELECT id, parentid, 1 AS level, CAST(id AS CHAR) path
    FROM TestTable
    WHERE id=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.id, p.parentid, level + 1, CONCAT_WS(' ', CTE.path, p.id)
    FROM CTE
    INNER JOIN TestTable p ON p.parentid=CTE.id
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
ORDER BY path;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5e002350885533d432ffc272ef3917eb

Comment: Works for single-digit id's, but as soon as the id values use multiple digits, it won't sort correctly. You might fix it with [LPAD()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) to make id values a uniform length.

Comment: Wow, Thank you, sir! Thank you for the quick response and it works!

Comment: @BillKarwin LPAD to where? Could you show your suggestion?

Comment: The CONCAT expression should be: `CONCAT(CTE.path, LPAD(p.id, 10, '0'))` assuming the id numbers are at most 10 digits (the maximum value of a 32-bit unsigned INT is 4294967295).

Comment: @BillKarwin Ah-ha! gotcha! Thanks!